# "command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1" при установке PycURL

Tags: python, debian, gcc, arm

Есть *HummingBoard* (*Cubox-i*) с *Debian*.

Пытаюсь установить *PycUCL* через `pip install pycurl`. Выдает следующую ошибку:

> error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1.

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` также не получается установить:

> E: Unable to locate package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi

Comment: Нужен более полный лог сборки, сообщение "... failed with exit status 1" само по себе несет очень мало полезной информации.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вот что именно выдает консоль [Код](http://pastebin.com/rrMixL2y)

Подробное описание сборки, вы найдете тут [Сборка](http://www.igorpecovnik.com/2014/08/19/cubox-i-hummingboard-debian-sd-image/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свою проблему я решил, не хватало следующего:

```
apt-get install libgnutls28-dev
```

Спасибо всем кто пытался помочь.

Comment: не вижу связи между: вашей ошибкой *"cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’"* и решением

Answer (score 1):

Судя по приведенным логам сборки у вас компилятор вызывается с неподдерживаемым флагом (stack-protector-strong). [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182042/pip-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-fstack-protector-strong) пишут что может помочь обновление gcc или изменение файла. Возможно, получится просто слить исходники и собрать их самому

Comment: к сожалению это не помогло ;(